# Redirecting a POST with FILES via PHP

Tags: php

I have a hardware device that is configured to submit a POST to a server (Server A). However, the device can't easily be reconfigured because of where it is located and I need the POST to go to Server B.

Is there a way to use PHP on Server A to redirect the POST with FILES to Server B?

I see a few related answers here, but none address FILES.

Thanks in advance?

Comment: use curl. Receive the entire request and re-do the entire request (including the files) with curl

Comment: You can probably take the tmp file from ServerA and then copy them to ServerB, but it might depend on how ServerA can talk to ServerB. I've done something similar with images using PHP's copy by making the files accessible to the internet and using the URL in the copy function.

Comment: cURL would work too. There are a few options for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache and can enable mod_proxy, an easier way may be to just set up a ProxyPass for the URLs you need to forward. Take a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse